# Play longer than 2 minutes audio with "Actions on Google"

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml), if you are using SSML for playing audio, you're limited to "120 seconds maximum duration".

Is there other way to start playing longer media (audio) with "Actions on Google" SDK on Google Home?

Example usage: Meditation sounds that can last longer than 2 minutes.

Comment: To clarify - do you mean the Assistant SDK, which lets you embed the Assistant in other devices and applications, or Actions on Google, which lets you build your own Actions that work with the Assistant on Google Home?

Comment: @Prisoner thank you for correction. I really mean "Actions on Google" as it named on site. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1):

As [responded](https://plus.google.com/+ValentynShybanov/posts/RYqckXXrmth) by [Leon Nicholls](https://medium.com/@leonnicholls) (Google Assistant Developer Programs Engineer), currently there is no way to play audio longer than 120 sec. However they are considering that in the future.

Comment: can i play audio longer than 120 sec using ssml tags?

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Media responses](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses). You can play MP3 file longer than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I created a Voice Metronome app which need to play for a long time. On the Google home, I was able to get it to play for 10 minutes. On the phone the limit was 2. I don't know if the new speaker devices have longer play times and I don't know how long they will allow this. Just an FYI.

Comment: How did you achieved 10 minutes? combiding `<break>` and `<audio>` tags? From my observation, they limit total time of audio playbacks (may be I am wrong). So could it be the situation that you got 10 minutes just because _sounds_ where 2 minutes long in total? I can not achieve more than 2 minutes on Google Home, even if I break audio into smaller parts

Comment: strange... I tried to use same approach by splitting media into smaller chunks, but on Google Home I have only 2 minutes playing in total... may be they limit it on some inner-selected basis...