# Can I launch app from my app for google home?

Tags: spotify, google-home, deezer

I have a problem i want to launch playlist of a music streamming application (spotify, deezer, ...) from my custom app for google-home (I think we call that action) but I doesn't find how to do that.

I have already try to play some sound with the  tag but with that you can just play 120 second from an audio file. And I need a way to launch app not just play music

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play longer than 2 minutes audio with "Actions on Google"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594333/play-longer-than-2-minutes-audio-with-actions-on-google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some returns from Google and they told me that actually we can't launch other app from our app

Answer (score 0):

I know of one way to do this but this would only work on a smartphone or tablet.

You could use the BasicCard, BrowingCarousel or (technically speaking but not recommended) Suggestion Chips to display a btn or link with the link to the playlist and spotify *should* catch that and open the app.

Comment: thanks for your answer but my app will only run on google-home :/